Trigger conditions don't match values in MAUI
In my .NET 8 MAUI application, I have a Label and the Text of the Label is being set from the code behind:
<Label
    x:Name="lblDropDown"
    Text="{Binding Placeholder, Source={x:Reference this}}"
    TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference this}}"
    FontSize="{Binding TextSize, Source={x:Reference this}}"
    FontFamily="{Binding TextFontFamily, Source={x:Reference this}}">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="Label">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition 
                    Binding="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                    Value="{Binding Placeholder, Source={x:Reference this}}" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{Binding PlaceholderColor}" />
        </MultiTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" 
                Binding="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                Value="{Binding Placeholder, Source={x:Reference this}}">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{Binding PlaceholderColor}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
<Label Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" />

And the result is as follows:

The issue is that I can't check with the MultiTrigger when, for example, the Text has the same initial value to change the color. For example, I like to change the color of the text to grey (PlaceholderColor) when the Text of the Label is the same as the Placeholder.
In the last line of the XAML, you see I display the value of the Text. This value is the same value as Placeholder but the BindingCondition nor DataTrigger is applied.

You can refer to trigger.

What is the 'this' refer to? And could you share the code behind about how you set the Text or Placeholder?
